# Java - Download zip from a SSL HTTP url (with keystore/trustore)

Tags: java, security, ssl, keystore

I'm trying to download a zip file from an url but the url returns a 404 page with the app.
When I try with firefox, it just asked the keystore so I put it and it works : I can download the ZIP file.

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code

```
                URL url = new URL(reportInfo.getURI().toString());
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();


                /*
                 * Keystore manager
                 */
                KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory
                        .getInstance("SunX509");
                String pKeyPassword = GSBConstants.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD;
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(new File(
                        cc.getWorkingDir() + File.separator
                                + GSBConstants.KEYSTOREJKS_NAME));
                keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
                keyInput.close();
                keyManagerFactory
                        .init(keyStore, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());


                /*
                 * Trustore manager
                 */
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                        .getInstance("SunX509");
                KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                InputStream trustInput = new FileInputStream(new File(
                        cc.getWorkingDir() + File.separator
                                + GSBConstants.TRUSTORE_NAME));
                String pTrustPassword = GSBConstants.TRUSTORE_PASSWORD;
                trustStore.load(trustInput, pTrustPassword.toCharArray());
                trustInput.close();
                trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

                SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),
                        trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(),
                        new SecureRandom());
                SSLContext.setDefault(context);

                SSLSocketFactory sockFact = context.getSocketFactory();
                con.setSSLSocketFactory(sockFact);


                // Check for errors
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                InputStream inputStream;
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    inputStream = con.getInputStream();
                } else {
                    inputStream = con.getErrorStream();
                }

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test.zip");

                // Process the response
                BufferedReader reader;
                String line = null;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    output.write(line.getBytes());
                }

                output.close();
                inputStream.close();
```

Any ideas ? 
I don't have any exceptions.

Comment: You say that you put the keystore in FireFox? Do you mean that you imported a certificate?

Could it be that Firefox has a trust chain for the root certificate but Java truststore does not?

Comment: yes sorry i import the certificate

Comment: I don't know. Do you know how can I check that?

Comment: The certificate you import is a client certificate needed to access the service right? The Server certificate of the service, is it self signed? Do you get a warning when accessing it that it is not trusted (selfsigned)? You can download this certificate by pressing the lock icon in firefox then import it in your java truststore.

Comment: Yes i have imported my p12 certificate into firefox. When I load the URL, I choose the good certificate and download the file without warning.

Comment: I don't know why, When i remove the trustmanagerfactory and put "null". the result is the same. But if i remove the keymanagerfactory, i have a handshake failure

Comment: Looks like it's a bit late for the response; however, just in case you are still struggling...    What you need to do is to save that Certificate you accepted in Firefox on your local hard disk and then add that to the JVM Trust Store. As soon as you have a Certificate in your JVM Trust Store, your handshake errors will magically disappear. :)